# Deleting properties in two ways, but only one works

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

**delete** removes property from some object.

```
function Man() {
  this.eye = 2;
  this.mouth = 1;
}
Man.prototype.walk = function (arguments) {
  console.log("Im walking.");
}

var man1 = new Man();
var man2 = new Man();

delete man1.constructor;
console.log(man1.constructor); // function Man()
```

Up there, by delegation of course, I am deleting the property of `man1`'s prototype, the `constructor` property. Well, at least that is my intention. But when I log, I still get the Constructor function.

However, this problem is fixed when

```
delete man1.constructor.prototype.constructor;
console.log(man1.constructor);  // function Object()
```

now what I get is empty Object. As I should.

My question is: why does that second solution work and the first one does not? Is it because of delegation? I have heard that the one that works `delete man1.constructor.prototype.constructor;` uses "implicit" reference. What does that mean? One more thing. Why am I still getting empty `Object` and no free memory?

Comment: `delete` only removes own properties: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ordinarydelete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why you get the constructor again ?

Because `delete` works only for the *direct/own* properties of the object, but your `Man` does not have a *direct/own* property with name `constructor`. `constructor` is in the prototype chain of the `Man` which comes from the `Man.prototype`. When you access that property it just goes and gets it from the prototype chain.

So from here you can also infer that properties from the prototype chain can  only be read, not modified. If you want to modify, you need a direct access.

> However, this problem is fixed when

In this case you have accessed actually the original object and delete it from that object. For that object `constructor` is a *direct/own* property.

Comment: Wait. By `Man` you mean the instances, like `man1`? You don't think of `Constructor` function? Also, you have said: _constructor is in the prototype chain of the Man which comes from the Object.prototype_.  I believe that it comes from `Man.prototype` object, not `Object.prototype`. Right?

Comment: You can check it using hasOwnProperty. Yes, from Man.prototype. I misstyped